# How would I load a database with multiple inconsistent headers?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a database with multiple headers like so:

```
site_no,datetime,00060_00003    
11481500,2019-10-05,7.54
[...]
site_no,datetime,00010_00001,00010_00002,00010_00003,00060_00003
11523000,2019-10-05,15.0,14.1,14.6,1920
```

I need to merge these into something that looks like this:

```
site_no,datetime,00010_00001,00010_00002,00060_00003    
11481500,2019-10-05,-1,-1,7.54,-1
11523000,2019-10-05,15.0,14.1,14.6,1920
```

The code that I currently have to do this is:

```
    df = pd.read_csv(outputFileName, false_values = ["***"], header=headerlist[0] )
    i = 1
    while i+1 < len(headerlist):
        newdf = pd.read_csv(outputFileName, false_values=["***"], skiprows=headerlist[i]-1, header = headerlist[i]).head(n=(headerlist[i+1]-headerlist[i]),)
        df.join(newdf, on = "datetime", how="outer")
        i = i + 1
    df.to_csv(outputFileName)
```

I get an error:

```
KeyError: 'datetime'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat one.csv
    site_no,datetime,00060_00003
    11481500,2019-10-05,7.54
$ cat two.csv
    site_no,datetime,00010_00001,00010_00002,00010_00003,00060_00003
   11523000,2019-10-05,15.0,14.1,14.6,1920
```

code:

```
df2 = pd.read_csv('two.csv')
df = pd.read_csv('one.csv')

pd.concat([df,df2], join='outer', join_axes=[df2.columns])
```

output:

```
   00010_00001  00010_00002  00010_00003  00060_00003  00060_00003        datetime   site_no
0          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN             7.54  2019-10-05  11481500
0         15.0         14.1         14.6       1920.0              NaN  2019-10-05  11523000
```

the pd.join or pd.concat works on entire data frame, you don't need to loop through the variables.

using merge: (from the documentation)

```
t = pd.DataFrame({'key':['foo','foo'], 'lval':[1,2]})
>>> right = pd.DataFrame({'key':['foo', 'foo'], 'rval':[4,5]})
>>> left
   key  lval
0  foo     1
1  foo     2
>>> right
   key  rval
0  foo     4
1  foo     5
>>> pd.merge(left, right, on='key')
   key  lval  rval
0  foo     1     4
1  foo     1     5
2  foo     2     4
3  foo     2     5
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) is what you want

You can read the data into a dataframe using normal pd.read_csv

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('one.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('two.csv')
```

Then apply pd.concat with `axis=0` and `ignore_index=True`. By passing `axis=0` here you are stacking the df's on top of each other. The columns that do not match will result in a NaN. You can do a `fillna(-1)` to change that to `-1` as per your requirement.

```
df1 = pd.concat([df1,df2], axis=0, ignore_index=True).fillna(-1)
```

The output of this will be:

one.csv will be df1:

```
    site_no    datetime  00060_00003
0  11481500  2019-10-05         7.54
```

two.csv will be df2:

```
    site_no    datetime  00010_00001  00010_00002  00010_00003  00060_00003
0  11523000  2019-10-05         15.0         14.1         14.6         1920
```

concatenated df1 will be:

```
    site_no    datetime  00060_00003  00010_00001  00010_00002  00010_00003
0  11481500  2019-10-05         7.54         -1.0         -1.0         -1.0
1  11523000  2019-10-05      1920.00         15.0         14.1         14.6
```